# ¿Cómo procesar las tildes y también el delimitador en Excel?

Tags: javascript, csv, utf-8, codificación

Hice un código JavaScript que recoge `labels` y sus valores asociados para convertir un formulario en un `CSV`.

La cosa es que en las especificaciones puedo poner el tipo de codificación que quiero, para que trate bien las tildes.

```
link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI(csvContent));
```

Además, si quiero que al abrir el `CSV` con Excel, me separe por `comas` en vez de `tabulaciones`, pongo `var csvContent = "sep=,\n";` como primera linea del archivo y sí los separa en columnas pero ya no trata las tildes.

**¿Cómo puedo tener ambos requisitos a la vez?**

---

Este es el código (también en [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg8td0Ln/38/)):

```js
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download, false);

    

function download(e) {
    
    data = [["ColumnaNombre","ColumnaDato"]];
    
    //var f = d3.selectAll("#csvForm > input")[0];
    
    var columnaNombre = document.getElementsByClassName("ColumnaNombre");
    
    var columnaDato = document.getElementsByClassName("ColumnaDato");
    
  for (var i=0;i<columnaNombre.length;i++) {
        //grab x[i].innerHTML (or textContent or innerText)
        data.push([columnaNombre[i].innerText, columnaDato[i].nodeName=="INPUT" ? columnaDato[i].value : columnaDato[i].innerText]);
  }
    

    
    console.log(data);
    
    var csvContent = "sep=,\n"; //charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";  "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF"
    data.forEach(function (d, i) {
        dataString = d.join(",");
        csvContent += i < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" +  encodeURI(csvContent));
    //link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "FormData.csv");
    link.click(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<table class="interlineado" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Matrícula:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2" class="ColumnaDato" color="#000080"> prueba</font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Departamento:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080"></font></td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font size="2" class="ColumnaNombre" color="#008080">Nombre:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080">Rrhh Desarrollador 01</font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font  class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Teléfono:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2"  color="#000080">
<input  class="ColumnaDato" name="PetTelefono" value="985"></font></td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font size="2" class="ColumnaNombre" color="#008080">Factoría:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2"   class="ColumnaDato" color="#000080"></font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Email:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080">prueba@prueba.com</font></td></tr>


</tbody></table>
</ul>

<p id="resultado"></p>

 <button id="download">Download</button>
```

Comment: Puede que esto te sirva [generating-csv-file-for-excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value) dice: 

 **If you have non-ASCII characters (encoded in UTF-8) in the file, you should have a UTF-8 BOM (3 bytes, hex EF BB BF) at the start of the file. Otherwise Excel will interpret the data according to your locale's default encoding**

Comment: @amenadiel ese EF BB BF es el que tengo tras UTF-8

Comment: En libreoffice siempre me lo reconoce como UTF8, pero no hay manera de saltarse el wizard de importación

Comment: @amenadiel si no pongo el delimitador, las tildes me las trata bien. es cuando pongo esa primera linea (que no sale en el excel) cuando las tildes ya no se tratan  pero si se separa en columnas

Comment: lois6b: Creo que es mejor usar el fragmento de código HTML/JavaScript/CSS de SOes ya que es un recurso interno en lugar de usar algo similar pero que es un recurso externo. Mas detalles en mi [respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1450/65) a una pregunta en [meta].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de usar `encodeURI` usa `escape`.

Ejemplo simple

```js
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download, false);

function download(e) {
  var encoding = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";  
  csvContent = "sep=,\n";
  csvContent += "niño,niña\n";
  csvContent += "melón,sandía\n";
  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encoding + escape(csvContent));
  link.setAttribute("download", "FormData.csv");
  link.click(); 
}
```

```html
<button id="download">Descargar</button>
```

Aplicado al código del OP

```js
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download, false);

    

function download(e) {
    
    data = [["ColumnaNombre","ColumnaDato"]];
    
    //var f = d3.selectAll("#csvForm > input")[0];
    
    var columnaNombre = document.getElementsByClassName("ColumnaNombre");
    
    var columnaDato = document.getElementsByClassName("ColumnaDato");
    
  for (var i=0;i<columnaNombre.length;i++) {
        //grab x[i].innerHTML (or textContent or innerText)
        data.push([columnaNombre[i].innerText, columnaDato[i].nodeName=="INPUT" ? columnaDato[i].value : columnaDato[i].innerText]);
  }
    

    
    console.log(data);
    
    var csvContent = "sep=,\n"; //charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";  "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF"
    data.forEach(function (d, i) {
        dataString = d.join(",");
        csvContent += i < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" +  escape(csvContent));
    //link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "FormData.csv");
    link.click(); 
}
```

```html
   
    
    <ul>
<table class="interlineado" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Matrícula:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2" class="ColumnaDato" color="#000080"> prueba</font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Departamento:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080"></font></td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font size="2" class="ColumnaNombre" color="#008080">Nombre:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080">Rrhh Desarrollador 01</font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font  class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Teléfono:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2"  color="#000080">
<input  class="ColumnaDato" name="PetTelefono" value="985"></font></td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="16%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font size="2" class="ColumnaNombre" color="#008080">Factoría:</font></b></td><td width="35%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font size="2"   class="ColumnaDato" color="#000080"></font></td><td width="18%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><b><font class="ColumnaNombre" size="2" color="#008080">Email:</font></b></td><td width="31%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><font  class="ColumnaDato" size="2" color="#000080">prueba@prueba.com</font></td></tr>


</tbody></table>
</ul>

<p id="resultado"></p>

 <button id="download">Download</button>
```

**Referencia:**

[Comentario](http://halistechnology.com/2015/05/28/use-javascript-to-export-your-data-as-csv/#comment-3101026153) de Lucky Garg en [Use JavaScript to Export Your Data as CSV](http://halistechnology.com/2015/05/28/use-javascript-to-export-your-data-as-csv/)

Comment: Perfecto, funciona tal y como lo quería. muchas gracias ^^